# CentOS future updates

Tags: centos

We have been using CentOS as the OS for some of our linux servers for quite some time now.

However, in a recent policy meeting, one of the colleagues said that there will be no more CentOS kernel updates after the recent kernel update to 3.10.0 and future CentOS updates will be focused on CentOS as more of a Desktop OS rather than a server OS.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat Linux source code back ports security updates. See https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting

CentOS rebuilds the source code for RHEL, so they inherit those back ports.. Including new device drivers for new hardware, etc.

So the Red Hat / CentOS kernel is not a standard 3.10.0 kernel, it gets things back ported from new kernels and security updates for the lifetime of the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

He may have read that they are doing more updates with the desktop UI. Even if that is true programs on Linux are mostly maintained by the original developers. The primary part the O.S. developers play is making the pieces fit and work together. Sometime this means maintaining your own version of a program but most of the time they repackage it and provide updated from the maintainer. Any program you are using should still receive updates no matter what direction the CentOS team focuses on.

The kernel could cause some problems but doubtful. If it does then you can always download the sources from CentOS and compile it with your own options selected Though from what I read it seems they are expanding there server market to Amazon cloud etc.

Comment: How can we know for sure that kernel updates will not stop. kernel updates are important for bugs fixing and system security, right?

Comment: While CentOS is under active development they will provide kernel updates. How they configure the kernel more efficient as a server or desktop.